# Custom transformations used in Sklearn Pipeline object for preprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

My question is about creating custom transformations based on a train set and reapply them on new observations. To achieve this goal I usually use Pipeline object from sklearn.

The transformation I want to build is a custom grouping for categorical variables. The method allows to choose the proportion under which a category is considered as rare. If the proportion of occurrence of a category is less than the specified proportion (parameter), then we classify (rename) this category as 'OTHER'.

The problem comes when there are some categories in the test set that does not occur in the train set. The code below raises the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot setitem on a Categorical with a new category, set the 
categories first
```

Here is the code I use:

```
trainDF = df[0:8000]
testDF = df[8000:10142]

class CustomBinningCategoricalFeature(TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, percRareClass):

        self.percRareClass = percRareClass
        self.rareClass = {}

    def fit(self, X, y = 0):

        for column_name in list(X.head(0)):

            if (X[column_name].dtype != np.dtype(float)):

                df = pd.crosstab(index = X[column_name], columns = 'count')
                df['prop'] = df['count']/df['count'].sum()

                self.rareClass[column_name] = df.index[df['prop'] < self.percRareClass].tolist()

        return(self)

    def transform(self, X, y = 0):

        for column_name in self.rareClass.keys():
            #X.loc[~X[column_name].isin(list(X[column_name].unique())), column_name] = 'OTHER'
            X.loc[X[column_name].isin(self.rareClass[column_name]), column_name] = 'OTHER'

        return X

pipeline = make_pipeline(CustomBinningCategoricalFeature(0.01))
pipeline.fit(trainDF)

transformed_testDF = pipeline.transform(testDF)
```

In the industry, it could happen that new categories occur. In this situation, we are facing at least two choices:

1. To not score new data if a category is unknown from the train set
2. As it is the first time that the category occur, we could consider it as a rare class, so we assign it the 'OTHER' category.

In our case, we want to choose the second option.

Do you know a way to code the fit and transform methods to use them in pipelines and apply the transformation on new data according to the second option above (assigning 'OTHER' to new category occuring in the test set) ?

Comment: If you want to use the second option, then during your training you need to have that "Other" category as well so the model considers it for prediction. You can do this by assigning some of the rarer known cateogories in training data to this new category.

Comment: Could you please give me some lines of code to see where you suggest to assign the ‘Other’ category in the train set? Do you mean in the fit, or in the transform part ? Thank you